# Btc bitcin juicy vegas

Tags: fraud

I won some money on juicy vegas and they told me to create a bitcoin account and send money via bit coin to release the funds, so I did but now they are saying that they didn't receive the funds and I'm out of £56

Comment: I am sorry to tell you, but you have almost certainly been scammed. Asking money to release money is a very common scamming technique.

Comment: I thought as much when they said that they had not received the funds and that iq barcode had timed out. I had reviewed the website before hand of the transaction and it seemed genuine but I'm guessing not. Any idea on how to claim it back?

Comment: If you have sent somebody untrustworthy money using Bitcoin, you don’t have recourse to claw it back unfortunately.